# Tableau 10.5 Percent of Total by dimension LOD Calculations

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

I have a Tableau Desktop 10.5 workbook of data showing projects my department manages and the time spent on each project by various departments. I need to provide the percentage of the project's total that each department spent on each project.

In the data, I have a dimension showing the total time spent on the project (Actual Hours) and each department has a total number of hours spent on the project (Total Hours).

I have a calculated field (% of Work Req Total Hours) with this formula summing the total hours for each department for each work req  and dividing it by the actual hours for that effort.

SUM(IF [Dept Desc] = [Dept Desc] THEN [Total Hours] ELSE NULL END) / (SUM(IF [Work Req] = [Work Req] THEN [Actual Hours] ELSE NULL END))

For most of the departments, this works as you can see below.

-- Contract M... spent 101 hours out of 2772.5 resulting in 3.6% of this project's total.

[Example workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRVDS.png)
However, in this example (effort C3211, CS PMO has a total of 2469 hours spent on the project across two manager codes. The sum is correct, but the formula I am using now computes the total hours for each manager code and divides it by the total hours and then averages those two percentages (12.65% and 76.39%) to get 44.52% for CS PMO when it should be 89%.

[PMO Details Averaging 44%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vejn9.png)

I cannot use the Table Calcualtion % of Total because it calculates each department's percentage of each effort as a percent of the total hours charged for ALL of the efforts whereas I need a per-effort percentage.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, and I'm relatively new to Tableau and table calculations, so any help or direction of what I should be researching is much appreciated.

Comment: Try a table calc, and experiment/study how partitioning and addressing work

Comment: You don’t need to type “ELSE NULL”. It’s implied

Comment: Thanks for the tip about else null—think I’ve been in excel too long.